# Smart solution for XenServer firewall?

Tags: linux, firewall, xen, xenserver, citrix

I've been searching for a smart solution for a XenServer firewall for about a month now. The documentation for the new default networking backend "openvswitch" is not that detailed and I can barely find guides to filter packages with OVS. The other possibility would be linux bridge with iptables (which I am going to evaluate in the next couple days).

How are you firewalling with you XenServers? Do you use the Dom0 for it, do you have a dedicated VM for it ... ?

Answer (score 0):

My implementation is by deploying a PV Guest dedicated to performing firewall duties. But you still should harden dom0, though.